# Two FIND_IN_SET in a single query is not working

Tags: php, mysql

Below is the table structure (invite table):-

```
id   user_id   doc_name        discussion_topic     invited_friends  accepted_invitation 
    
1     1        IEP Form-1.docx   first topic        2,3,4             NULL
```

Now:

When I did query:-

```
SELECT * from invite WHERE  (FIND_IN_SET(2,invited_friends) > 0)
```

I got this record perfectly(shown above).

But when I did:

```
SELECT * from invite WHERE  (FIND_IN_SET(2,invited_friends) > 0) AND (FIND_IN_SET(2,accepted_invitation) =0)
```

I didn't get the above record, not any error too.

Also when I did:

```
SELECT * from invite WHERE user_id <>1 AND (FIND_IN_SET(2,invited_friends) > 0) AND (FIND_IN_SET(2,accepted_invitation) =0)
```

Again I didn't get the above record, or any error too.

*Actually the scenario I have to check that a given id(example 2)  is not equal to `user_id` and must be in `invite_friends`(never be null) and not in `accepted_invitation`(`accepted_invitation` will be `null` or `,` separated id values).*

What mistake I did in the last two queries?

Note: I am using these queries directly in `PHPMyAdmin`

Comment: try with`(FIND_IN_SET(2,IFNULL(accepted_invitation, '')) = 0`

Comment: You could set default value for these columns as 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) for the column names:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   invite 
WHERE  user_id <> 1 AND
      (FIND_IN_SET(2, IFNULL(invited_friends, 0)) > 0)  AND 
      (FIND_IN_SET(2, IFNULL(accepted_invitation, 0)) = 0);
```

Check the SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/98d95/9

Answer (score 2):

You should use this

Replace '= 0' to 'is null'

```
SELECT * from invite WHERE  (FIND_IN_SET(2,invited_friends) > 0) AND (FIND_IN_SET(2,accepted_invitation) is null )
```

Comment: This is incorrect because when values are in accepted_invitation but they are not found, the function will return 0.

Answer (score 2):

To check your scenario use

```
SELECT * from invite WHERE user_id <>2// check user ID not equal to 2
AND (FIND_IN_SET(2, invited_friends) > 0)// 2 present in invited_friends
AND ((FIND_IN_SET(2, accepted_invitation) = 0)|| (FIND_IN_SET(2, accepted_invitation) IS NULL))// check 2 is null and not present in accepted_invitation
```